# Convert a string/integer to superscript in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

Is there a built in .NET function or an easy way to convert from:

```
"01234"
```

to:

```
"\u2070\u00B9\u00B2\u00B3\u2074"
```

Note that superscript 1, 2 and 3 are not in the range [\u2070-\u209F](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf) but [\u0080-\u00FF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

EDIT: I hadn't noticed that the superscript characters weren't as simple as `\u2070`-`\u2079`. You probably want to set up a mapping between characters. If you only need digits, you could just index into a string fairly easily:

```
const string SuperscriptDigits = 
    "\u2070\u00b9\u00b2\u00b3\u2074\u2075\u2076\u2077\u2078\u2079";
```

Then using LINQ:

```
string superscript = new string(text.Select(x => SuperscriptDigits[x - '0'])
                                    .ToArray());
```

Or without:

```
char[] chars = text.ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
{
    chars[i] = SuperscriptDigits[chars[i] - '0'];
}
string superscript = new string(chars);
```

Comment: The codepoints for superscript 1-3 are somewhere else: http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf

Comment: I think it would be easier using `String.Concat()` instead of the string constructor with the LINQ approach.  That is unless there's a significant performance difference between the two.

Comment: @Jeff: I don't see how that would be easier.

Comment: @Jon: The consructor overload requires an array of characters while a generic overload of `Concat()` accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` so the `ToArray()` call wouldn't be necessary.  That's my reasoning anyhow.

Comment: @Jeff: I can see a `Concat<IEnumerable<T>>` and a `Concat<IEnumerable<string>>` call, but not `Concat<IEnumerable<char>>`. I suspect the former would call `ToString` on each element, which would create a bunch of strings unnecessarily. Also, these calls are only available in .NET 4, whereas my approach would also work in .NET 3.5. I think I'd rather stick with ToArray and the constructor :)

Comment: @Jon: Fair enough.  And it does have a slight performance difference as you pointed out.  I'll have to try to remember to avoid this with character conversions.

Comment: There is a typo with the digits \u20b9 should be \u00b9