# Adding strings in superscript 3

Tags: c#, string, superscript

Following Code:

```
string a = "Adding substring" + "\xB2";
Console.Write(a);
```

Will give : `"Adding substring2"`. 2 will be superscript as expected.

How can I do the same with number 3.

Comment: Nice post by Jon Skeet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431601/convert-a-string-integer-to-superscript-in-c-sharp

Comment: You can find the Unicode codes for all super/subscript characters [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

Comment: If you are running on windows, you can look at the characters in a font with Char Map.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace `2` with `3` in `"\xB2"`

```
string a = "Adding substring" + "\xB3";
Console.Write(a);
```

And you will get:

```
Adding substring³
```

Comment: Gotta love simplicity ;)

Answer (score 3):

The [unicode character for superscript-3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b3/index.htm) is `\xB3`